# <?= tags not working in codeigniter version 2.1.0

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter version 2.1.0  the

`<?=   ?>`

tags not working,

I have applied the tags like this `<?=$company['name']?>` and i tried  `<?= $company['name']?>` and `<?php $company['name']?>` none of these are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) configuration directive is probably set to false on your server.

You also forgot the echo in your last call, it should read:

```
<?php echo($company['name']); ?>
```

Since the [echo shorthand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) only works for the short tag, i.e. `<?= ... ?>` and *not for* `<?php= ... ?>`